# Fairly complex .htaccess redirect via PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

We have recently merged all of our sub-directories in one database and I would like to setup a redirect so that users do not experience 404 across that sub-directory.

We have a sub-directory called /students/ which had links like this

www.domain.com/students/lab.php?assigment=345

now with new URL and everything merged we will have that same page at

www.domain.com/students/lab.php?assigment=11562

Because we are using a PHP Framework when I keep students nothing seems to work, so is there a way to capture incoming URL via . htaccess and only if it has **students** directory name, I can run a PHP script on it?

I have already created a long list of 301 redirects from old URLs to new ones. So as long as I can capture incoming URL, I can do the 301 easily.

Thank you for taking time reading this.

Comment: If I read this right, the page `students/lab.php` is the same for both the old and new URL schemes. In which case, mod_rewrite really isn't going to help you, you'll have to look at `$_GET['assignment']` in the PHP page and act appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you can employ [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for this, with either a [`txt`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) file or an external program or script [`prg`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg).

There are at least two caveats, however

- It can only be used in the main server config or in a virtual host environment.
- You must be very careful with your script, because it might severely impact your server's performance.

Comment: I got pretty far with this and now only need to fix up few things. But RewriteMap is definitely a way to go for this sort of things. Thank you!